# Execute delete query with a space appended at the end and without a space

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I have a DOB field in my table, in my previous version of the app I had inserted this record after using .trim() function to truncate the spaces at start and end. An ideal cell looks like 2014-11-12. Now I updated the app and somehow missed on using trim before insert. A space is appended to this value at the end and then its inserted into the DB. Now the records in this column are mixed - Dates with spaces at the end and dates without spaces at the end.

I want to execute a delete query on this table:

1)    `Delete from Samba where DOB = '1994-11-18 '` - with the space

2)     `Delete from Samba where DOB = '1994-11-18'` - without the space

How can I trim the DOB object returned from the DB so that I have a single query for both the cases? Something like (I may be conceptually incorrect, pardon me):

```
Delete from Samba where DOB.trim() = '1994-11-18'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using LTRIM(RTRIM()) would eliminate any white spaces.

```
DELETE FROM Samba WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(DOB)) = '1994-11-18'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Works like sex! Thanks bro!